# How to determine the size of a single key in Redis

Tags: memory, redis, key, size

How can I know the size (in KB) of a particular key in [redis](/questions/tagged/redis)?
I'm aware of `info memory` command, but it gives combined size of Redis instance, not for a single key.

Comment: What would be your use of a key's value size ?

Answer (score 19):

I know this is an old question but, just for the record, Redis implemented a `memory usage <key>` command since version **4.0.0**.

The output is the amount of **bytes** required to store the key in RAM.

*Reference: https://redis.io/commands/memory-usage ‏*

Comment: Note that it is the number of bytes that a "key and its value" require to be stored in RAM and not just the bytes required to store the "key" as mentioned by bruno

Comment: Note that with `redis-py`, this can be executed as `redis.Redis.execute_command("MEMORY USAGE", key)`

Answer (score 4):

You currently (v2.8.23 & v3.0.5) can't.

The `serializedlength` from `DEBUG OBJECT` (as suggested by @Kumar) is not indicative of the value's true size in RAM - Redis employs multiple "tricks" to save on RAM on the one hand and on the other hand you also need to account for the data structure's overhead (and perhaps some of Redis' global dictionary as well).

The good news is that there has been talk on the topic in the OSS project and it is likely that in the future memory introspection will be greatly improved.

Note: I started (and stopped for the time being) a series on the topic - here's the 1st part: https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-ram-ramifications-i

Answer (score 1):

`DEBUG OBJECT <key>` reveals something like the `serializedlength` of key, which was in fact something I was looking for... For a whole database you need to aggregate all values for KEYS * which shouldn't be too dfficult with a scripting language of your choice... The bad thing is that [redis.io](http://www.redis.io/) doesn't really have a lot of information about [DEBUG OBJECT](http://www.redis.io/commands/debug-object).

Answer (score 1):

Why not try

> APPEND {your-key} ""

This will append nothing to the existing value but return the current length.

Comment: This will only return the length for a string, does not provide any information about memory consumption

Comment: The question didn't talk about memory consumption. The answer just assumed it was about memory when seeing "info memory".

Comment: this might not be universal but works for me, upvoted

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the length of a key (string): [STRLEN](https://redis.io/commands/strlen)