# How to get the memory size of a list in Redis?

Tags: memory, redis, redis-cli

I'm storing a very large list of strings in `Redis` and I'm trying to figure out if there is a command (or any other way) to get the memory used by that list. Any suggestions?

I went over the list of [`Redis commands`](http://www.redis.io/commands) by couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: You may try with https://github.com/gamenet/redis-memory-analyzer. It supports LIST so you may get memory statistic about you data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Redis doesn't provide this type of introspective memory abilities. Your best bet at the moment is to [`DUMP`](http://redis.io/commands/dump) the list and then [`RESTORE`](http://redis.io/commands/restore) it to an empty database. Use [`INFO`](http://redis.io/commands/info)'s *memory* section from target database before & after restoring the list and subtract the former from the latter to get the size estimate.

Comment: I see, toda @ItamarHaber. I just now noticed this very similar [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735096/…), but I will leave the question open for this answer.

Comment: @Forge ein be'ad ma ;)